# devise_token_auth forget password API shows Use POST /sign_in to sign in. GET is not supported error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise-token-auth

Following this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/47761138/7818637 I am designing forgot password flow APIs on rails where I am using `devise_token_auth` gem for authentication.

**1. A POST call to send a Password Reset Email**

URL: `http://localhost:3000/client/auth/password`

form-data: `{email: 'john@gmail.com', redirect_url: 'http://localhost:3000/client/auth/sign_in'}`

[image: post call to send a password reset email]

**2. A GET call to verify the password reset token (clicked in email)**

I am receiving the the following URL on my console containing `redirect_url` and `reset_password_token`:

`http://localhost:3000/client/auth/password/edit?config=default&redirect_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fclient%2Fauth%2Fsign_in&reset_password_token=ZBsx64Gk1VBraM3THZTn`

When I call on this URL, I am receiving the following error:

```
Use POST /sign_in to sign in. GET is not supported.
```

[image: call to verify the password reset token]

**What I have already tried:**

Following the issue [here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/754) I have found that I am already using `include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken` in my controller.

**Console Logs:**

[image: console logs]

Answer (score 0):

When the users clicks the url in your email you redirect them to */password/edit* path. In this action you verify the user. If everything goes right the user will be redirected in *redirect_url* which is the *sign_in* path in your case.

You should change the *redirect_url* in your email and create an action and a view in which the user will be redirected. In this new view you will have the fields so the user can reset the password. Make sure that the new url will use 'GET'. On form submission redirect user to sign_in path so he/she can log in with their new password.

Please read https://devise-token-auth.gitbook.io/devise-token-auth/usage/reset_password for more info.